# Functions involving integration in sympy

Tags: python, function, sympy

I'd like to define a function *f*(*x*), and then define another function that it its integral.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
f = lambda x: x**2
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
g = lambda x: integrate(f(x),x)
```

Problem is, if I enter

```
g(2)
```

it fails. This is because it's holding the right-hand side of *g*(*x*) unevaluated until I call it. It passes the 2 into the integrate, and tries to integrate with respect to 2.

I can force the right behavior if I write:

```
g = lambda x: integrate(f(s),s).subs(s,x)
```

but that seems really clunky.

Is there a way to evaluate the integral symbolically in terms of *x*, and then define the function *g*(*x*) with that result?

Comment: I guess you want to use `Integral` rather than `integrate` but I'm not really sure what it is you want to do. I think maybe you're confused about the difference between the lambda variable `x` and the symbol `x` because those are not the same.

Comment: @Oscar: Yes, you could replace the `lambda` variable `x` with anything (since it's just treated as a local variable). I'd like *f* (*x*) to be anything in terms of the symbol *x*, and define *g* (*x*) to be its integral with respect to *x*. So when I then enter *g* (*foo*), I get the integral of *f* (*x*) wrt *x*, evaluated at *x* = *foo*. `Integral` does not work for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `g` using a dummy variable `foo` -- `x` is your real variable and can't be used as the lambda's variable:

```
>>> g = lambda foo: integrate(f(x), (x, foo))
>>> g(2)
8/3
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems inconsistent with other implementation in Python, like list comprehension. For instance, if you define a list `x` which has a bunch of numbers in it, then `[x**2 for x in x]` and `[foo**2 for foo in x]` do the same thing.

Comment: There is enough context to translate `[x for x in x]` to `[_ for _ in x]` since it is obvious that you want to iterate over `x` but for `lambda x: x`, the `x` on the rhs can only be assigned one unambiguous meaning: the `x` that was passed instead of the `x` in the global context. So if you want to use a global `x` in the lambda you can't use `x` as a parameter of the lambda.